# Automatic horizontal centering of beamer frame content

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment

I would like to set some global option so that the content of all beamer frames is horizontally centered with respect to the page.  In other words, I want to achieve the effect of wrapping all frame content in `\centering` ... `\par`, but *without* actually having to type that in every frame:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%% This is the sort of thing I want, but it only works in article mode
% \setbeamertemplate{frame begin}{\centering}
% \setbeamertemplate{frame end}{\par}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \framebox{Automatically centered -- how?}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \centering
  \framebox{Centered by hand}
  \par
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I have searched the documentation for some sort of hook that I can set, but to no avail.  The tantalizingly named `frame begin` and `frame end` templates work only in article mode.  How can this effect be achieved?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use `centering`

```
\documentclass[center]{beamer}

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{frame}
  \framebox{Automatically centered!}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

result:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: It works!  And so simple too.  I feel really stupid for not thinking of just moving the `\centering` command to the document-level scope.  Thanks!