# Remove all frame content from article mode in beamer

Tags: beamer, beamerarticle

What is the best way to remove all frame content from a beamer presentation when the article mode is being used? Below is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}
%\documentclass{article}\usepackage{beamerarticle}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{This is frame 1}
Content of frame 1, but shouldn't be in the article
\end{frame}

This text should appear in the article, but not within the presentation.

\begin{frame}{This is frame 2}
Content of frame 2, but shouldn't be in the article
\end{frame}

This text should appear in the article, but not within the presentation.

\end{document}
```

The idea is that the beamer presentation is the lecture, whereas the inter-frame text will be homework questions that will be typeset separately.

**EDIT**

I searched under global frame options and ideally I would like to have something like the solution to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78954/automatic-horizontal-centering-of-beamer-frame-content) question:

```
\documentclass[presentation]{beamer}
```

except the option somehow needs to be within the `article` class!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify as overlay option if something is only meant to be in the presentation with `<presentation>`. In the same manner you can use `<article>`.

Some examples where you can use these overlay options are

```
\begin{frame}<presentation>
```

or

```
 \mode<article>{This text should appear in the article, but not within the presentation.}
```

---

```
%\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}
\documentclass{article}\usepackage{beamerarticle}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}<presentation>{This is frame 1}
Content of frame 1, but shouldn't be in the article
\end{frame}

This text should appear in the article, but not within the presentation.

\begin{frame}<presentation>{This is frame 2}
Content of frame 2, but shouldn't be in the article
\end{frame}

This text should appear in the article, but not within the presentation.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps also mention `\mode<article>`?

Comment: Thanks for the fast solution! Is it possible to globally add the `<presentation>` to all frames?

Comment: @Geoff Maybe? But with a good editor that knows "replace all" it should be easy to change all frames at once [unless you are already using overlay options for frames].

Comment: @Geoff If the _entire content_ is different between the two versions then having it one source seems a bit odd!

Comment: @Joseph I agree, but in this case there is sense (IMO): the idea is to keep exercises close to the input information, if I decide to move/remove parts of my lectures, the exercises move along accordingly.

Comment: @Geoff Currently I don't think this can be set (it requires `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification`, which only applies in presentation mode): I'm working on some 'refresh' stuff for `beamer, so feel free to [log an issue](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/new).