# Automatically Generating Article from Beamer Presentation Draft

Tags: beamer

I'm interested in the reverse conversion from this post:
[Automatically Generating Beamer Presentation Draft from Article](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/397055/automatically-generating-beamer-presentation-draft-from-article)

In particular, I would love to have some Python code to strip our all the beamer commands and replace them with suitable basic latex commands so that I can easily convert a beamer presentation into nice code to add to a larger document that is not a beamer presentation.

Yes, the package "beamerarticle" is really great, but is suboptimal solution to my problem.

Comment: Welcxome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Please provide some examples of "beamer commands" that you think should be stripped off programmatically. Incidentally, with which "basic latex commands" would you "replace" common "beamer commands" such as `\begin{frame}` and `\end{frame}`?

Comment: Yes, I suppose strip \begin{frame} and \end{frame}, \frametitle, \framesubtitle, spacing such as \vspace, the columns environment \begin{columns} \column{} .... which perhaps could be just stripped, or perhaps could be made into side by side text in the article.  Commands like \only<3>{ } or \visible<3->{ }, ... there may be more, but I think that's most of them.

Comment: Here is an example file that I would like to convert to a article or book format:  https://texample.net/tikz/examples/prims-algorithm/