# Display frames in article mode

Tags: beamer

**My question**

`ignorenonframetext` in `beamer` enables to have only what's between `\begin{frame}` and `\end{frame}`. But in `Beamerarticle`, how can we skip code between `\begin{frame}` and `\end{frame}` (i.e. it keeps only `nonframetext` in article mode) and without adding overlay on each frame ?

I don't see an equivalent to (non existing) `ignoreframe` option in  beamerarticle.

I'd really like to avoid the heavy overlays `\begin{frame}<presentation>`

[image]

**Context**

To avoid text between frames in `beamer`,I use `\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}`.

But when working in `beamerarticle`, is there an equivalent to `\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}` that'd do the job of (non exisiting)

`\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[ignoreframe]{beamerarticle}`

Based on [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347810/remove-all-frame-content-from-article-mode-in-beamer?noredirect=1&lq=1) I understand that it would require, to use `overlay` (like `\begin{frame}<presentation>`) that IMO put loads of weight on typewriting, I'd need to replace all my simple `\begin{frame}`. I assume in my workflow that a slide will necessarily appear in my presentation...).

I probably mis-use the `handout` option of `beamerarticle`...

MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[envcountsect,handout]{beamerarticle}


\begin{document}

\section{First section}

%\only<article>{% I'd like to avoid the chore to place overlays on all my text that is not in a frame)
Long  text that will appear only in article mode (here is a `article.cls`). Long  text that will appear only in article mode (here is a `article.cls`). Long  text that will appear only in article mode (here is a `article.cls`). Long  text that will appear only in article mode (here is a `article.cls`). Long  text that will appear only in article mode (here is a `article.cls`). Long  text that will appear only in article mode (here is a `article.cls`). Long  text that will appear only in article mode (here is a `article.cls`). Long  text that will appear only in article mode (here is a `article.cls`). Long  text that will appear only in article mode (here is a `article.cls`). Long  text that will appear only in article mode (here is a `article.cls`). 
%}


%\only<article>{% I'd like to avoid the chore to place overlays on all my text that is not in a frame)
    \begin{itemize}
        \item It will
        \item appear
        \item in the article
    \end{itemize}
%}

\begin{frame}
{Frame skipped in article}
    \begin{block}{Block title}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item first
        \item Second
        \item third
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All credit to SamCarter's answer [here](https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1093). It enables to create an intermediate format in `beamer` where in `article mode`, you can see the content of the frames. Particularly useful to articulate what's to be in `article` and key info in `beamer`.

[image]

"Similar to the approach in https://groups.google.com/d/msg/de.comp.text.tex/ycdX_TPNjjM/sK17Tse1AgAJ one could add the beamer overlay specification as default in article mode:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
%\documentclass{beamer}
​
\usepackage[envcountsect]{beamerarticle}
​
​
\makeatletter
\mode
<article>
{
  \long\def\beamer@@@@frame<#1>[#2]{%
    \global\let\insertframetitle=\@empty%
    \global\let\insertframesubtitle=\@empty%
    \beamer@slideinframe=1\relax%
    \refstepcounter{framenumber}%
    \beamer@slideinframe=0\relax%
    \beamer@anotherslidefalse%
    \beamer@masterdecode{beamer,#1}%
    \ifbeamer@anotherslide%
      \let\beamer@howtotreatframe\beamer@dosingleframe%
    \else% no slides in frame
      \let\beamer@howtotreatframe\beamer@donoframe%
    \fi%
    \beamer@slideinframe=1\relax%
    \beamer@howtotreatframe}
}
​
​
\makeatother
​
\begin{document}
​
test
​
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Title of the frame}
    \framesubtitle{Subtitle of the frame}
​
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
        \item first
        \item Second
        \item third
    \end{itemize}
​
\end{frame}
​
\begin{frame}<beamer>
    \frametitle{Title of the frame}
    \framesubtitle{Subtitle of the frame}
​
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
        \item first
        \item Second
        \item third
    \end{itemize}
​
\end{frame}
​
\end{document}
```

(one could probably shorten the code a bit with some xpatch magic…)

Caveat:

Frames will even be hidden if they are explicitly labelled for the article, e.g. \begin{frame} won’t work "